# Convert mm'ss'' to mm:ss in excel

Tags: excel, time

How I can convert a register of time of for example 28'30'' to 28:30 in excel?
I have tried to change the formatting in custom but it doesn't work. There is any formula to change it?

Thanks!

Comment: internally is it `28'30"` a string or is it already a time with some format?, if it is an string, have you tried parsing it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it as a time in minutes and seconds (if it was originally a string in A2):-

```
=TIMEVALUE("0:"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,"'",":"),"""",""))
```

and then format cell as time.

Answer (score 0):

```
=LEFT(A1,2)&":"&MID(A1,4,2)
```

for text-to-text conversion.